# Making toast from alert dialog positive Button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-toast

I want the alert dialog when clicking on the positive button to show toast, but instead, It shows an erorr!

the code

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Create new ?")
            .setMessage(" Do you want to create new msg ?!")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes ? ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(this," Ready to Create New Msg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

the error msg

```
Error:(38, 30) error: no suitable method found for makeText(<anonymous 
OnClickListener>,String,int)
method Toast.makeText(Context,CharSequence,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to 
Context)
method Toast.makeText(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to 
Context)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `YourActivity.this` or `getApplicationContext()` instead of just `this` in the first parameter of `makeText`

Answer (score 0):

You must use Context correctly. Instead of this, use dialog.getContext() or NameOfYourActivity.this when creating the Toast.